# Symmetric Encryption cyclic redundancy check

Tags: c#, encryption, uwp, windows-10-mobile

I need to encrypt some data before writing to the DB and decrypt on reading from the DB.

I've used the code available in this guide here: [Encrypting and Decrypting data in an Universal Windows App](https://laurentiu.microsoft.pub.ro/2016/04/05/encrypting-and-decrypting-data-in-an-universal-windows-app/)

When ever I try to decrypt I get the error:

> Data error (cyclic redundancy check). (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070017)

I thought it was because the key was different as I instantiated the `SymmetricEncryptionHelper` object once for encrypt then again for decrypt. To combat this I changed the class to be a singleton but I still get the same error:

```
public class SymmetricEncryptionHelper
{
    private readonly IBuffer randomBuffer;
    private readonly IBuffer randomBufferCBC;
    private readonly CryptographicKey cryptographicKey;
    private readonly string algorithmName;
    private readonly SymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider cryptingProvider;

    private static SymmetricEncryptionHelper _instance;

    public static SymmetricEncryptionHelper Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (_instance == null)
            {
                _instance = new SymmetricEncryptionHelper();
            }
            return _instance;
        }
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Instantiate with a random generated buffer (not an option if
    /// you want to persist the encryption to disk)
    /// </summary>
    private SymmetricEncryptionHelper()
    {
        algorithmName = SymmetricAlgorithmNames.AesEcbPkcs7;
        cryptingProvider = SymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider.OpenAlgorithm(algorithmName);
        randomBuffer = CryptographicBuffer.GenerateRandom(cryptingProvider.BlockLength);
        randomBufferCBC = null;
        cryptographicKey = cryptingProvider.CreateSymmetricKey(randomBuffer);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Instantiate with a custom generated buffer (good for
    /// persisting the encryption to disk)
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="randomBuffer">The custom generated buffer</param>
    private SymmetricEncryptionHelper(IBuffer randomBuffer)
        : this()
    {
        this.randomBuffer = randomBuffer;
        cryptographicKey = cryptingProvider.CreateSymmetricKey(randomBuffer);
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Instantiate with a custom generated buffer (good for
    /// persisting the encryption to disk) and with a custom
    /// generated CBC buffer (is using CBC algorithms)
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="randomBuffer">The custom generated buffer</param>
    /// <param name="randomBufferCBC">The custom generated CBC buffer</param>
    private SymmetricEncryptionHelper(IBuffer randomBuffer, IBuffer randomBufferCBC)
        : this(randomBuffer)
    {
        this.randomBufferCBC = randomBufferCBC;
    }

    private bool IsMultipleOfBlockLength(IBuffer binaryData)
    {
        return (binaryData.Length % cryptingProvider.BlockLength) != 0;
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Encrypts a given string
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="data">Data to be encrypted</param>
    /// <returns>An encrypted string in Unicode</returns>
    public string Encrypt(string data)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(data))
        {
            return data;
        }

        var binaryData = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(data).AsBuffer();
        if (!algorithmName.Contains("PKCS7") && IsMultipleOfBlockLength(binaryData))
            throw new Exception("Message buffer length must be multiple of block length !!");
        var encryptedBinaryData = CryptographicEngine.Encrypt(cryptographicKey, binaryData, randomBufferCBC);
        return Encoding.Unicode.GetString(encryptedBinaryData.ToArray());
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Decrypts a string in Unicode
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="encryptedData">An encrypted string in Unicode</param>
    /// <returns>The decrypted string in Unicode</returns>
    public string Decrypt(string encryptedData)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(encryptedData))
        {
            return encryptedData;
        }

        try
        {
            var encryptedBinaryData = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(encryptedData).AsBuffer();
            var decryptedData = CryptographicEngine.Decrypt(cryptographicKey, encryptedBinaryData, randomBufferCBC);
            return Encoding.Unicode.GetString(decryptedData.ToArray());
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

Can anyone see where I'm going wrong - I've googled the error but can't seem to find an answer that works for me.

Additionally - once the app is closed I'm going to lose the key, so what's the best practice here? Should I save the key in the PasswordVault?

Comment: Do not use ECB mode, it is not secure, see [ECB mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Electronic_Codebook_.28ECB.29), scroll down to the Penguin.

Answer (score 3):

Don't trust random code on the internet, period. You need to know what you're doing. ECB mode encryption is insecure for textual messages - and most other cryptographic operations really.

Your problem is directly relying on the decoding of the ciphertext generated within the encryption method (using `Encoding.Unicode.GetString`, the bad Microsoft name of UTF-16LE). Now a ciphertext always contains of random bytes. And pairs of these bytes don't always constitute a valid UTF-16LE encoded character. So usually those are left out from the stringyfied ciphertext or they are replaced by a substitute character.

Obviously if substitute characters have been introduced then that particular block of ciphertext will be decrypted into a block of random data, making your CRC check fail.

---

If you need to show the ciphertext as text for some reason then base64 encode it.

Comment: What encryption do you suggest for strings?

Comment: Anything but ECB, with a random IV (prefixed to the ciphertext). GCM is a good choice because it also authenticates the ciphertext. Note that the IV for GCM needs to be 12 bytes and should *never* repeat.